# Why the Linked List class is not showing add method correctly in myeclipse 2013 pro on macos x

Tags: java, collections

I am using a linked list class to add elements.To get the elements one by one i have used Iterator to get only even nos.

Problem

1 l.add(p) in the code is showing error when i am trying to take numbers from 1 to 10

and when i put in l.add("p"); //no error why ?

2 While trying to get Integer Object i could not apply modulas operator,but why ?

Here is the code
package app;
import java.util.*;
public class IteratorDeo1
{
    public static void main(String s[]){

```
    LinkedList l=new LinkedList();
        for(int p=0;p<=10;p++)
            {
              l.add("p"); 
            //l.add(p); here 1st  error comes why
            }
    System.out.println(l);
    Iterator i=l.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        Integer I=(Integer)i.next();
        if( I % 2 == 0 )  here comes 2nd error
          System.out.println(I);
        else
            i.remove();
    }
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Comment: Your for-loop probably isn't doing what you think, but it's hard to tell from this snippet. Optional curly braces are not really optional in practice. My advice is to always use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing `"p"` 11 times, which is a literal `String`, not an `Integer`. After adding `"p"`, you're adding `"2"` which is another literal `String`, not an `Integer`.

To make sure you're adding `Integer`s or an object of a specific type, you should use generics:

```
LinkedList<Integer> l=new LinkedList<Integer>();
for(int p=0;p<=10;p++)
    l.add("p"); // compiler error here: you're adding a String, not an Integer
```

In case you're using Java 1.4 or prior (which is very odd in these times), then you cannot use generics but you still can *protect* yourself from this `ClassCastException` by using `instanceof` operator:

```
Iterator i=l.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    Object current = i.next();
    if (current instanceof Integer) {
        Integer I = current;
        //rest of your code...
    }
}
```

Also, unboxing and autoboxing are in Java since version 5. In Java 1.4 or prior, you have to obtain the `int` value of the wrapper and perform the modulus operator manually:

```
if (I.intValue() % 2 == 0) {
    //rest of code...
}
```

Comment: yes that is the problem .I want to add Integers.It is not allowing me showing error.

Comment: Well, now you know the problem. Just add real `Integer`s to your `LinkedList`, not `String`s.

Comment: Okay i know there too if i am using like for(int p=0;p<10;p++) l.add(p) .Then also it is showing error

Comment: have you seen the `LinkedList<Integer>` usage of the Generics? This will Limit the LinkedList to contain only integers. Otherwise it can only contain `Object`.

Comment: yes it is saying parametrized types are not available for 1.5 or higher.What to do then?

Comment: @Jack make sure you're using Java 5 for your projects. Why are you using Java 1.4 or prior? Is that how your project is configured? If (sadly) yes, then the compiler cannot help you and you must be sure to add `Integer`s to your collection.

Comment: holy what!? stop using Java 1.4! Even don't try to use Java 5, as its End-of-Life was reachet 2009. Also Java 6 reched it's EoL in 2013, so try Java 7 oder better Java 8!

Comment: I am new to mac os x while using java. I installed myeclipse software sir.May be 2013 version is using it 1.4 Thankx,i will install new version of eclipse

Comment: @Jack Java version doesn't depend on Eclipse. Looks like you have Java 1.4 as default for your projects. I highly recommend you to read on tutorials about how to properly install latest version of Java in your OS, then install eclipse (that depends on Java, not vice versa). Also, I recommend using eclipse Luna or Mars.